# Avoid loops in matlab in multiplictaion

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, product

This function allows me to multiply two matrices with Matlab. I need to avoid loops because they take too much time. I don't know how can I do it, please help me.

```
  function a = matrice_multplication(A, B) 
     [r1 , c1] = size(A);
  [r2 , c2] = size(B);
% % prevent unappropriate matrix size
if c1 ~= r2
    disp ('*** le nombre des  colonne de la premiere matrice doit etre egale ou nombre des ligne de la deuxieme matrice ***')
end
for i = 1 : r1
    % Vary each column of matrix B
    for j = 1 : c2
        % Reset every new element of the final result
%          c=cell (r1 , c2)
        s = [0,0,0,0] ;
          % Vary each column of matrix A and row of matrix B
          for k = 1 : c1
              % Display every element to take into account
  %           disp(  A{i,k})
  %      disp   (  B{k,j})
  % f= ) 
  s  =plus(s,quatmultiply(A{i,k},B{k,j}) );
  %            
        end
  %         % Assign the total of the appropriate element 
  %         % to the final matrix
  c{i,j} = s;
  %                disp ( c{1,1})
  %           disp ( c{1,2})
  %             disp ( c{2,1})
  %               disp ( c{2,2})
   a{i,j} = c{i,j};
  % disp (a{i,j})
      end
  end
          end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `A*B`. Matlab has default support for matrix arithmetic operations without loops.

Comment: i knooow but i know to use this function because n had projected it to quaternions

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Comment: i use the same function to multiply matrix of quaternions  by replacing * with quatmultiply and + by plus  because * dosen't exist for quaterions

Comment: @AmalKostaliTarghi Then you really need to add that information to your question. As it stands, it seems like a really odd thing to do to rewrite one of the most basic functions in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I think for you case, it would be much better to use mex

Since it is just simple looping, using mex file is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but it seems like you're just trying to perform quaternion multiplication on a collection of quaternions.

Having read the definition (i.e. predigested analytical formula)of quaternion multiplication on wikipedia, one could write this definition to multiply two individual quaternions:

```
function Out = multiply_two_quaternions (a, b)
  assert (size (a, 1) == 4, 'Quaternions should be expressed as vectors of 4 elements (i.e. rows)');
  assert (size (b, 1) == 4, 'Quaternions should be expressed as vectors of 4 elements (i.e. rows)');

  % definition according to wikipedia#  
  Out = ...
    [a(1) * b(1) - a(2) * b(2) - a(3) * b(3) - a(4) * b(4); ...
     a(1) * b(2) + a(2) * b(1) + a(3) * b(4) - a(4) * b(3); ...
     a(1) * b(3) - a(2) * b(4) + a(3) * b(1) + a(4) * b(2); ...
     a(1) * b(4) + a(2) * b(3) - a(3) * b(2) + a(4) * b(1) ];
end
```

In this context, a quaternion is represented as a 4-element *vector* (i.e. vertical array). So for example, 1 + 2i + 3j + 4k would be `[1;2;3;4]`.

Now, say you have a 'collection' of 10 quaternions. This can easily be represented as a matrix, with 4 rows, and 10 columns, where each column is a quaternion.

So the question becomes, how can I multiply these 10 quaternions in a single vectorised operation, using my `multiply_two_quaternions` function, rather than loop ten times?

You *could* use that specific function with something like `arrayfun`, but the simplest way would be to redefine your function as a `multiply_two_arrays_of_quaternions` function which performs element-wise multiplications across columns, e.g.

```
function Out = multiply_two_arrays_of_quaternions (a, b)
  assert (size (a, 1) == 4, 'An array of N Quaternions should be expressed as a matrix of 4 rows and N columns');
  assert (size (b, 1) == 4, 'An array of N Quaternions should be expressed as a matrix of 4 rows and N columns');

  Out = ...
    [a(1,:) .* b(1,:) - a(2,:) .* b(2,:) - a(3,:) .* b(3,:) - a(4,:) .* b(4,:); ...
     a(1,:) .* b(2,:) + a(2,:) .* b(1,:) + a(3,:) .* b(4,:) - a(4,:) .* b(3,:); ...
     a(1,:) .* b(3,:) - a(2,:) .* b(4,:) + a(3,:) .* b(1,:) + a(4,:) .* b(2,:); ...
     a(1,:) .* b(4,:) + a(2,:) .* b(3,:) - a(3,:) .* b(2,:) + a(4,:) .* b(1,:) ];
end
```

Example usage:

```
>> A = randi(10, [4, 10]), B = randi(10, [4, 10]), a = A(:,1), b = B(:,1)
A =
     3     4    10     3     7     3     1    10     3     6
     2    10    10     5     8     4     3     8     5     3
     3     5     5     6     3     5     9     5    10     5
     5     2     2     3     2     6     1     6     6     7
B =
     7     1     1     2     5     9     1    10     9     9
     4     9     3     8     8     4     8     7     6     1
     4    10     4     2     8     7     6     7     2     5
    10     8     7     7    10     2     5     9     3     2
a =
     3
     2
     3
     5
b =
     7
     4
     4
    10

>> multiply_two_quaternions(a,b)
ans =
   -49
    36
    33
    61

>> multiply_two_arrays_of_quaternions(A,B)
ans =
   -49  -152   -54   -67   -73   -36   -82   -45   -41    12
    36    66    67    70   110    16    50   153    81     8
    33   -17   -19     7     7    82     8    90   117    76
    61    89    97   -11   120    68   -48   171    13    85
```

If this is not what you had in mind, then I apologize, but your code is very confusing. You talk about matrix multiplication but you try to access A and B as cells ... and then I have no idea what quatmultiply does because you haven't shown me its definition, or the format of A and B (i.e. how you represent your quaternions). If you're using cells, it would be a very inefficient way to represent them as you're stuck with loops for any operations on them.

Also, as a general comment, do try to write properly indented, clean, well documented code, with meaningful variable and function names etc :p
It makes a lot of difference!

Comment: thank you it works but the problem is like you do mat2cell and you perform the multiplication but this is not what i need to multiply 2 quaternions we cae use the function quatmultiply (a,b)  and plus to add to quaternions .  so in my function i suppose that i have 2 matrix for example         a ={ [  1 2 3 4] , [ 1 1 1 1]} and  b= { [ 1 2 3 4] , [ 1 1 1 1 ] ; [ 1 5 9 7 ] , [ 4 5 6 7 ]} my function but the probleme that the loop tale too much time so i need and alternative thank you

Comment: by the way, just pointing out that the `plus()` function and the `+` operator are equivalent (in fact, `+` essentially calls `plus()` under the hood). In fact, you can see this if you try to add two things that cannot be added together, such as an array with a cell: `[1] + {1}`, matlab will respond with the error `Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`, indicating matlab effectively called the `plus` function for those two arguments under the hood. So there really is no benefit using `plus()` over `+`, especially since the latter is probably clearer.